# Crop out complementary regions from an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have coordinate regions of an image. I am cropping out images from those coordinates. Now, I need complimentary regions of what that is cut out, with respect to the original image. How do I go about using Pillow?

Comment: what do you mean by "complementary regions"?

Comment: consider a segment in an image being cropped out. The other regions in that image is what i mean by complimentary

Comment: if you remove a part from inside the image you get something that cant be described by a subimage. typically that is described by a mask. to do so you create a white 1-channel image and paint the unwanted parts black. now when you perform an action on a pixel you first test whether the mask is active. many functions support masks.

Comment: if you only want to crop away outer parts you can create simple subImages with the cv::Rect objects.

Comment: @Micka could you please give an example ?

Comment: I can only serve with c++ code, sorry

Answer (score 3):

If you crop a region you basically create a new, smaller image.

A complementary operation to that would be to fill the region with some value you consider invalid or zero as you will still have an image of the original size. Technically you cannot remove a region from an image. you can just change or ignore it.

```
PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle(xy, fill=None, outline=None)
```

is something I found quickly. Maybe there is something better. Just crawl through the reference.